# How to call external REST service from WSO2 Business Process?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to call external initialization rest web service on generate key in API manager. I want to send userID, emailAddress, name etc as a parameter in above service.

Could you please help me to achieve this. Can we do this using BPM or will have to modify API manager source code.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, your requirement is to call some external service after/before approving a key generation request.

For that, you can configure a workflow as mentioned in [this doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+a+Key+Generation+Workflow).

And you can write your custom implementation as per [this doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Customizing+a+Workflow+Extension).

Comment: Thanks Bhathiya... I tried to configure BPS by using above links. But in API manager I am getting exception "[2016-10-18 18:43:16,138] ERROR - application-add:jag java.lang.NullPointerException: null.
".